# what can be used as merged fields [[Data: ]] value in custom Email Resource file

Tags: docusignapi

We are creating DocuSign Envelope via DocuSign DSAPI API call.  We need to show custom Envelop Email message body to all envelopes all Signer recipients using Custom Branding Email Resource File template. What envelope metadata value can be retrieved using [[Data: ]] in the custom master Email Resource File template? Can the Envelope Custom Fields values provided in the Create Envelope API Call be retrieved using merged fields [[Data: ]]?

Comment: Is your integration with DocuSign new? If so, please do not use SOAP (DSAPI). Use the eSignature REST API. The SOAP API has not updated with new eSignature features for a couple of years now.

Comment: It's existing since 2016, now just add one new create envelop SOAP operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an official list of Resource File mergefields that I'm aware of, and which mergefields become available depend on what you're doing at a given time. For example [[Data:RecipientName]] and [[Data:RecipientEmail]] work in most places in the branding field as well as email subject / blurb, but they aren't all like this.

Due to the complexity, size, and implications of altering these files, Customer Support on the DocuSign end is prohibited from assisting with alterations to resource branding files, but what you can do is load the file into a utility like Notepad++ and do a search through the entire document for instances of [[Data:, then check the output list. That should give you a fairly large sample of what's available.

Regards,

Matt